# Using SQL Server Always Encrypted with classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

We have a business application that was written a long time ago using classic ASP. Now we want to utilize the Always Encrypted feature of SQL 2016. From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-client-development) I saw that my only option is to use Microsoft ODBC driver 13.1, however that is not well supported using VB script because not all datatypes work.

Other than rewriting the whole application is there another way of utilizing Always Encrypted with classic ASP?

Is support going to be added in some future release of the driver?

Answer (score 3):

The `oledb` driver is [deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access/) and not available for newer version of SQL Server.

[image]

The good new is the that `Microsoft` admitted they have made a mistake:

> However, during subsequent reviews it was determined that deprecation
>   was a mistake because substantial scenarios within SQL Server still
>   depend on OLE DB and changing those would break some existing customer
>   scenarios.

and the `oledb` driver is no [undeprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2017/10/06/announcing-the-new-release-of-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/). The new version will be released in March 2018. Unfortunately, the first version is going to support only SNAC 11.0.x functionalities, so nothing new that comes with SQL Server 2014+ is going to be supported:

> The new release of OLE DB will not support Transparent Network IP
>   Resolution, Always Encrypted, Azure AD Authentication, Bulk Copy and
>   Table Value Parameters to begin with.

You can wait for the new version of the driver that is going to support Always Encrypted. Otherwise, you can use two connections - one using the new ODBC driver where AE is needed, and one using the current OLEDB driver in order not to rewrite everything.